# SQL Generation of Insert statements

Tags: sql-server

I have the following script that I would like to add to a stored procedure.  Right now, when I run this the SELECT statement prints out all the INSERT statements.  I would like to run these insert statements automatically from within my stored procedure.

I've tried various ways by executing dynamic sql but I haven't been successful mostly due to the system tables my script references.  Is there anyway to generate proper INSERT statements and run them at the same time?

I'm using SQL Server for this.

**MY CODE:**

```
DECLARE @tablename as varchar(255) = 'tblsmoker'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (SELECT 'INSERT INTO tblCheck (ColumnName,ColumnValue,SID,SName,RID,RName)VALUES (''' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''',NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL);'
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename))
print @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

This code is giving me:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: dynamic sql is the way.   If you tried it and were unsuccessful, please post your attempt so that we can debug it.

Comment: Please do not use the syntax `set ... = (select)`. It is hurting my eyes. All you really need is `select @sql = 'insert into...' from ... where ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STUFF the insert statements into another variable, and then finally use dynamic sql to execute the variable.

Be sure to separate the INSERT statements inside the variable with a semi-colon.

Try this slight modification of your dynamic sql attempt:

```
DECLARE @tablename as varchar(255) = 'tblsmoker'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO tblCheck (ColumnName,ColumnValue,SID,SName,RID,RName)VALUES (''' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ''',NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL);'
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
print @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: You were close, you just need to concatenate the SQL variable for each row.

Comment: I updated my code to do the concatenation and the query executes but when I check the tblCheck table - NO Rows returned.

Comment: What does @SQL look like when you PRINT it before you EXEC it?

Comment: I got it.  I needed to add this: DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you have to set the variable to a blank space before populating it, otherwise the concatenation doesn't work.   Glad you got it.

Comment: @TabAlleman Do you have an extra bracket after `OBJECT_ID(@tablename))` left over from the original?